# Авторизация парсера vk.com на node.js

Tags: node.js, вконтакте, парсер

Пишу на *node.js* парсер `vk.com`. Не получается авторизоваться.

Использую *request*, *tough-cookie-parser*, *cheerio*. Схема такая:

Первым запросом открываю `m.vk.com`, забираю оттуда форму, у формы беру *action*, на *action* постом отправляю *email* и *pass* соответственно.

И тут мне *вк* сообщает, что какие-то проблемы со входом.

*Кукисы* отрабатывают нормально (ручками поправлена частичная перезапись *кукисов*), *request* отправляется с флагом `followAllRedirects = true`, пробовал на всякий случай прикидываться *хромом*, но все же безрезультатно.

Буду рад услышать мнение, если кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой задачей.

Comment: почему не хотите один раз получить `access_token` для `standalone` приложения (будут доступны все методы)?

Comment: С учетом, что мне не удалось прорваться через ручную авторизацию, возможно, это единственный для меня вариант. Но тут смущает отсутствие "автономности". Т.е. так или иначе мне необходимо будет приложение в вк и нужно будет отдавать руками в браузере ему доступ. В целом, это мелочь, но если вы знаете как это побороть, то будет просто замечательно

Comment: [Прямая авторизация](https://vk.com/dev/auth_direct) по паролю – тоже вариант, если вы пишете что-то полезное/легальное, т.к. надо об этом договариваться напрямую с ВК. Не парьтесь по поводу приложения в ВК – так забанили бы ваши аккануты, а так – приложение : )

Comment: Ок, спасибо информацию. В общем-то ничего нелегального не планируется - даже не собираюсь писать спам бота :)